# Why doesn't <leader> commands work in my installation of vimwiki?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

My Vimwiki doesn't start with leader + ww command, only with `:VimwikiIndex`.

I think it's related to leader.

`:echo mapleader` generates two errors:

> E121: Undefined variable: mapleader

and

> E15: Invalid expression: mapleader

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `mapleader` is not defined, then the leader key defaults to `\` (see `:h mapleader`). So your wiki should start by typing `\ww`.

If you want to redefine you global leader key, you have to set the `mapleader` variable in your vimrc file, i.e. to set it to the <kbd>Space</kbd> character:

```
let mapleader = " "
```

It's important to put it in your vimrc file, because it will be run *before* plugins are loaded; if you run this command in the command line, it will not change the existing mappings, then you actual mapping will still be `\ww`.

Please note that, as explained in the doc of the plugin you are talking about, you can also define your own custom mapping which will replace `<leader>ww`, by running:

```
:nmap [YOUR MAPPING] <Plug>VimwikiIndex
```

For example, to open your wiki with <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>:

```
:nmap <space>w <Plug>VimwikiIndex
```